# Using git submodules as poor mans git lfs

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, scp, git-lfs

TL;DR:

Should i use git submodules as a way to include large data in a repository so that the main repository does not bloat?

i am using git to keep track of configurations,settings and scripts for analysis of weather stations i manage for my university. Each Station has its own repository.
On top of that i am using gitlab to host the remotes and keep track of issues with these stations. I really like this workflow.

Now theses stations produce a lot of data in different formats. Some generate just a few MB/month and some, in rare cases, 4GB/month running for multiple years.

I already manage the data with a database(influxdb and grafana) where the data is simplified a little bit for monitoring and quickliy visualising data.
But i really want to keep the RAW original Data somewhere, in case of some issue with the database and just as a dumb backup. Mostly these are csv, json or some other textbased files. And i want that backup to be redundant, reliable and accessible. (Longterm the data will go into some kind of AWS glacier but thats another story)

Obviously, i dont want to keep it in the main repo for the station since this will bloat the repo and introduce problems on gitlab. But i also like the thought that the data is connected somehow to the station it belongs to.

### So how do i store the data without bloating my repo?

#### 1. Just store it on a file server and document it then..

So this one is kind of lame and does not feel complicated enough :D. No seriously since the number of stations will grow and i sometimes want to just do something like `git clone --recurse-submodules ...` and have everything i need for that station, i want the data somehow to be related to the repo.

#### 2. Thats what git lfs is made for..

I think this would be the most obvious solution, but i have one problem with that. I would need to maintain my own instance of gitlab on a server that has enough storage since the limit on gitlab.com is 10GB. Maybe i will manage my own instance in the future where this restriction does not exist but i think i want a dedicated local server for that.
But i dont want to manage my own raid and everything that comes with reliable backup storage. That i want to outsource to some storageprovider or the datacenter at our university. In the gitlab docs is a section about [hosting lfs externally](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/#hosting-lfs-objects-externally) but it seems like this external storage needs to support lfs as well.? And it does not seem like i just need to install git lfs there... So maybe still possible, but i guess setting up the backend for that is more complicated.

#### 3. Using submodules like a fool

My idea was to just use an extra repository for the data. This repo would be hosted on a cheap dedicated fileserver with enough space and ssh connection. I then would add this remote as a submodule to the mainrepo. I tested this already and it works but:

##### a. Adding files is slow

i expected this, its ok

##### b. compressing when pushing and cloning is slow

no way around that i guess..

##### c. writing and receiving is slow

`Writing objects: 100% (78/78), 2.28 GiB | 4.24 MiB/s, done.`

`Receiving objects:  25% (24/95), 153.55 MiB | 4.56 MiB/s`

Why? Isnt this just a ssh connection? It tops out at around 4MiB/s while i know that my connection is a lot faster. Around 100MiB/s when using scp to the same server in both directions

I kind of like this solution the most since it does require the least amount of additional software to get it working.

May i get punished by the git gods.

Is it possible to optimize the submodule workflow or should i do it differntly since this just is not what git is made for? I guess there is a very straight forward way doing this which i am not seeing because i am in tunnel vision right now.